# Animating a view but its subview's constraints aren't sticking

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am trying to create a navigation bar with a button that expands it down with a list of options. Currently I have a UIView `fakeNavigationBar` with a default height of 64.0. When expanded it's 410.0. I have a very small view that represents the bottom border line of the nav bar `lineView`. I have added a constraint like so:

```
let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: lineView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: fakeNavigationBar, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        fakeNavigationBar.addConstraint(bottomConstraint)
```

Now when I animate the navigation bar I am simply increasing the height of it. However my `lineView` is not sticking to the bottom of this. What could I be doing wrong? Shouldn't it remain pinned to the bottom of the `fakeNavigationBar`? Any pointers on this would really be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you seeing lot of constraints error in debugger? bottomConstraint is not the only constraint that you should add for your line view. It should also have leading / trailing space with respect to its superview and also its height.

Comment: maybe update layout in your animation block, like           fakeNavigationBar.setNeedsLayout()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        fakeNavigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
    })